# Stackable modal popup : Bootstrap on second modal first modal not completed got shaded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am new to Bootstrap.

I faced one problem. I want bootstrap modal inside the another bootstrap modal means nested modal popups.
So I found the solution of bootstrap modal is "stackable bootstrap modal".

Reference
"http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/"

Here, this works if all the nested popup having same height and width.
My problem is that, My first popup is little big in height and width and another second popup which opens after  first popup having less height and wdth.

But second modal is not covering  the first modal completely.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what you want. If you want the second modal to cover the first modal, can you not simply make the second modal larger using CSS? Can you provide a jsfiddle / bootply or a picture?